# How to publish Scalastyle results in Jenkins Maven job?

Tags: maven, jenkins, publish, scalastyle

We have a Scala project and use Maven and Jenkins for building it. Now we also want to use Scalastyle for static code analysis. 
It works fine in the IDE and if I use a Jenkins freestyle job. The output file is created and Jenkins shows a nice graph with the style warnings and errors.

However, if I use a Jenkins Maven job, the "Checkstyle trend" remains empty, although the xml file is there and has the right name (checkstyle-result.xml).

I found [this](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-17287). The discussion there is a bit confusing, but I understood that publishing the Scalastyle results should also work for a Maven job.

Did I get that wrong? Or is there in fact a way to make Jenkins publish the Scalastyle results for my Maven job? Or some kind of workaround? (Apart from using a freestyle job or SBT...)

Comment: You may want to check https://www.codacy.com to easily use Scalastyle and other static analysis rules for your Scala projects. It tracks the evolution over time and reports new issues introduced on every commit/pull-request.

Answer (score 4):

After trying out some things, I found the solution. All I needed was a Scalastyle entry in the root pom of my multi-module project that looks like this:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scalastyle</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalastyle-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <sourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
                <testSourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
                <configLocation>scalastyle_config.xml</configLocation>
                <outputFile>${project.basedir}/checkstyle-result.xml</outputFile>
                <outputEncoding>UTF-8</outputEncoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The important part here is *${project.basedir}*. I tried it before without and it didn't work.

In the project configuration in Jenkins I give the *scalastyle:check* goal in the section *Build* -> *Goals and options*, e.g.

```
clean install scalastyle:check
```

Under *Build settings* I ticked the checkbox *Publish Checkstyle analysis results*.

Now Jenkins publishes the Scalastyle results. One problem remains, however: Jenkins doesn't seem to pick up my Scalastyle config file (scalastyle_config.xml) but uses the scalastyle-maven-plugin's default rules. At least that's what I suspect, because for the same project I get more Scalastyle warnings in IntelliJ (which uses my custom config file) than in Jenkins...

UPDATE: I was wrong with that. Jenkins does indeed pick up my custom rules. Nevertheless it shows more Scalastyle warnings than IntelliJ does. I'll look into that later.